# Duplicate folder names when renaming using bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have folder **Example** in which I work. When I want to work in Test environment, i rename folder **Example_Test** to **Example** but before this I should change name of previous **Example** folder (which is currently DEV) to **Example_DEV** and vise averse

Heres is my code in batch file:

```
cd C:\Users\User
if not exist Example_DEV goto TEST

MOVE Example Example_TEST
MOVE Example_DEV Example
goto finish

:TEST
MOVE Example Example_DEV
MOVE Example_TEST Example

:finish
```

But when I run a bat file I get  **Example** and **Example_DEV** (correct) or **Example_TEST** and  **Example_TEST**(this folder duplicated, this is a problem)

Colud you help me please?

Comment: If I use command RENAMEinstead of MOVE I got the same problem

Comment: Can you explain your question clearer? I don't really understand what you want?

Comment: I just want to rename two folders according to their current names.

Comment: If i have Example and Example_TEST I need rename them like Example_DEV and Example and vice averse

Comment: this is not possible, you can't have two folders with the same name, so the problem seems to lie in the way you are viewing them.

Comment: I created 2 folders "Example" and "Example_TEST", after I run your code, it works fine, 2 folders have renamed to "Example_DEV" and "Example

Comment: provide the error message and the folders that are present _before_ and _after_ the probem occurs...

Comment: I have tried it at my own laptop at home and it works good as I expected.  So now I need to understand why the same code make duplicated folder names on  pc at work

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you are starting with the correct conditions? Either (Example and Example_TEST), or (Example and Example_DEV) must exist to start with.